# View 3D model through moving smartphone around. Can I utilise a game engine?

Tags: ios, 3d, game-engine, gyroscope

I need to create an app for iphone (primarily, preferrably for android and wp8 as well) that will act like a window in virtual reality. Basis is a 3d model (collada) of a neighborhood.
User will navigate through 3D model by walking and moving the phone around. I don't want to utilise a camera, just compass, gyroscope and GPS.
Can I achieve this by using a game engine? Is this too demanding a tast for a beginner programer?
Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: It should be relatively easy to do using Unity 3D.